# select all item that belong to one host

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following relations

```
Supplies            
sid     1       2       3       4
sname   Jason   David   John    Peter
address 1a      2b      3c      4d


Parts                       
pid     10      20      30      40      50
pname   Head    Body    Hand    Leg     Arm
color   red     blue    green   white   red


Catalog             
sid     1   1   2   2   3   4   1   1   4   4   1
pid     10  20  20  30  30  40  30  40  10  50  50
cost    100 200 150 150 130 125 50  180 123 126 120
```

and I want to select the sid of suppliers who supply every red or green part.
I  think that it means that `it not exist that green or red parts that not supplied by him.`

So I do the following query but it return null, I think it should return  sid is 1.

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Suppliers S
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT P.pid
FROM Parts P
WHERE P.color = 'red' OR P.color = 'green'
AND NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C
WHERE C.pid = P.pid
AND C.sid = S.sid
)
)
```

How do I fix it? Thank in advance.

Comment: Set up a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with sample data, please?

Comment: Okay, I will do it right now.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48c1b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is correct, except for the missing parenthesis in the `OR` that causes the wrong results (`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`). It should be:

```
WHERE (P.color = 'red' OR P.color = 'green')
```

or:

```
WHERE P.color IN ('red', 'green')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the supplier who supplies parts with both red and green colors, then you can use a query similar to this:

```
select s.sid
from supplies s
inner join catalog c
  on s.sid = c.sid
inner join parts p
  on c.pid = p.pid
where p.color in ('red', 'green')
group by s.sid
having count(distinct p.color) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ef3/2)

Or a better way as @ypercube pointed out:

```
select s.sid
from supplies s
left join catalog c
  on s.sid = c.sid
left join parts p
  on c.pid = p.pid
 and p.color in ('red', 'green')
group by s.sid
having count(distinct p.pid) = (select count(*)
                                from parts 
                                where color in ('red', 'green'));
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ef3/12)

Comment: I think the joins should be `LEFT` joins and last condition: `having count(distinct p.pid) = (select count(*) from parts where color in ('red', 'green'))`

Comment: @ypercube maybe I am missing something in your comment, but that gives a wrong result -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ef3/10

Comment: Yes, you are right, I meant this: [fiddle-2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31ef3/12)